# gis2web plugin in QGIS

Tags: qgis, java

when i use Leaflet, in gis2web plugin, and select Match project CRS my Open Street Map disappears however when i use OpenLayers option then number from the depth lines disappear (although not all)

Could not- Match project CRS cause some significant disadvantages, under Leaflet?